# My Razzle Terser build is broken ''Unexpected token: punc (.)'

Tags: reactjs, terser, razzle

I have a Razzle app and build is broken. It doesn't make sense as the error shown in build result points to something that doesn't exist in my code. This is the error message from Terser:

```
'Unexpected token: punc (.) [webpack://./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[4]!./src/Components/ImageUploader/ImageUploader.tsx:35,33][static/js/client.8ef62a8a.js:23168,34]\n'
```

and the code this error refers to this piece:

[image: Terser error]

This is my `razzle.config.js` file:

```
const path = require('path');
const LoadableWebpackPlugin = require("@loadable/webpack-plugin");
const { loadableTransformer } = require('loadable-ts-transformer');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    'typescript',
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
  ],
  buildType: 'iso-serverless',
  target: 'web',
  modify: (config, { target, dev }, webpack) => {
    config.resolve.extensions = config.resolve.extensions.concat(['.ts', '.tsx']);
    config.module.rules.push({ test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader' });
    config.module.rules.push({ test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|ico)$/i, loader: 'file-loader' });

    if (dev) {
      if (target === 'node') {
        config.plugins = config.plugins.filter(p => p.constructor.name !== 'HotModuleReplacementPlugin');
        config.entry = config.entry.filter(e => e !== 'webpack/hot/poll?300');
      }
      if (target === 'web') {
        config.devServer.https = true;
        config.devServer.pfx = process.env.RAZZLE_PFX;
        config.devServer.pfxPassphrase = process.env.RAZZLE_PFX_PASSPHRASE;
      }
      config.output.publicPath = config.output.publicPath.replace('http://', 'https://');
    } else {
      if (target === 'node') {
        config.externals = [];
      }
    }

    return config;
  },
  modifyWebpackConfig(opts) {
    const config = opts.webpackConfig;
    const filename = path.resolve(__dirname, "build");

    if (!opts.env.dev) {
      config.output.publicPath = '/public/';
    }

    if (opts.env.target === "web") {
      config.plugins.push(
        new LoadableWebpackPlugin({
          outputAsset: false,
          writeToDisk: { filename },
        })
      );
    }

    if (opts.env.target === "web" && opts.env.dev) {
      config.devServer.https = true;
      config.devServer.pfx = process.env.RAZZLE_PFX;
      config.devServer.pfxPassphrase = process.env.RAZZLE_PFX_PASSPHRASE;

      config.output.publicPath = config.output.publicPath.replace('http://', 'https://');

      // config.plugins.push(new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
      //   eslint: {
      //     files: './React/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
      //   },
      // }));
    }

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(t|j)sx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'ts-loader',
      options: {
        getCustomTransformers: () => ({ before: [loadableTransformer] }),
      },
    });

    return config;
  },
};
```

And this is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "razzle start",
    "build": "razzle build --noninteractive",
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production node build/server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@loadable/component": "^5.15.0",
    "@loadable/server": "5.15.0",
    "@types/loadable__component": "^5.13.4",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.12",
    "@uiw/react-md-editor": "^3.8.4",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "express": "4.17.1",
    "grommet": "^2.17.4",
    "grommet-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "grommet-styles": "^0.2.0",
    "i18next": "^20.4.0",
    "razzle": "4.0.5",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-i18next": "^11.11.4",
    "react-image-crop": "^9.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "5.1.2",
    "react-toastify": "7.0.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.14.5",
    "@loadable/babel-plugin": "^5.13.2",
    "@loadable/webpack-plugin": "^5.15.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "@types/react-loadable": "^5.5.6",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.8",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.28.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.28.5",
    "babel-preset-razzle": "^4.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^12.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.0.8",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^6.3.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "loadable-ts-transformer": "^1.0.0-alpha.3",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "razzle-dev-utils": "^4.0.5",
    "razzle-plugin-typescript": "^4.0.5",
    "ts-loader": "9.2.5",
    "typescript": "4.3.5",
    "typescript-loadable-components-plugin": "^1.0.2",
    "webpack": "5.50.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
}
```

Can you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem and a workaround. Terser cannot compile `?.` (possible nulls). So I replaced

`UploadBase64: result?.toString(),`

with

```
// @ts-ignore: Object is possibly 'null'.
UploadBase64: result.toString(),
```

This is not the very best solution but it works fine.